# Spawning and monitoring concurrent tasks with Python and Flask

Tags: python, mongodb, web-applications, flask

I have a larger application which automates several data aggregation tasks for an end-user. I'm wrapping this application with a web-based interface using `Flask`. Both of these applications are wrapped and joined with a `MongoDB` back-end via a `Docker` container.

The end-goal is for the user to start and monitor tasks via the web front-end (storing the on-going process information in the MongoDB instance).

What I'm missing is the glue between the `Flask` front-end and my own back-end. I need a method for starting a process from a web request, storing and monitoring that process, and administering that process from subsequent web requests (starting, stopping, etc.).

Note: This particular application will run a max of two or three processes at once and needs to stay within the confines of being able to run on a docker instance with limited memory/CPU (the back-end code simply makes web requests and aggregates data). Therefore, `Celery` (as prescribed in an answer from a similar question) is not ideal as it's far too bloated for the simple implementation I need.

Comment: have you considered using maybe mozilla's circus or supervisor? although only for process management

Comment: Circus looks like a decent implementation for process management. However, I still would like a method for the processes communicating back with the front-end (to give status/results).

Comment: Have you considered ipython's multiprocessing package?

Comment: If you're looking for bare-bones, your Flask front-end can start the back-end processes in a non-blocking way using `subprocess.Popen()` and some sort of pid-file-plus-kill to stop them. As far as any other monitoring is concerned, the back-end processes could send progress information to MongoDB.

Comment: I imagine this large existing application has some sort of API to start and monitor tasks. Can you add some information on the design of this API?

Comment: The existing application doesn't include an API for spawning tasks. Instead what I have is several smaller .py files that perform different tasks by interfacing with the larger application. Ideally, the web app would invoke a process that started instances of these .py files depending on what the end-user is asking for.

Comment: I've worked on similar systems before, my approach (pre-migration to AWS) was to use the Celery task queuer.

It was as simple as adding a method as a item to the queue, then getting information back from Celery about it every 5 seconds via an AJAX call to the Flask app.

Comment: Would you recommend AWS for small projects? I'm curious how the pricing model adapts to small deployments.